# OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener could not start on local computer

Tags: oracle11g

i installed the oracle 11gR2 in windows 7, but when i try to start the service OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener  from service.msc that service could not start saying "OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener service started and then stopped.some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services on programmes.

Please advice me.

Thanks and Regards,

tanni

Comment: another useful answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28141225/631527

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it:

I figured out what the problem was and fixed it.
The problem was caused by a mis-configuration of the listener.ora file. 
The listener.ora file was still pointing to my

```
      (HOST = <old server name>)
```

Once I made the change to reflect the current server, I had to run the command: "C:\lsnrctl start" then had to start the C:\ORADATA\PCPW\admin\brunner.exe
And finally to restart the service OracleOraDb11g_home1ClrAgent

By default, the listener.ora file is located in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory on UNIX operating systems and the ORACLE_HOME\network\admin directory on Windows

Comment: restarting the `OracleServiceORCL` service was enough for me after correcting the host name in `listener.ora` file

Comment: Check if Oracle_HOME is correctly set or not and then restart listener...it worked for me.